# Move elements 1 after the other jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to create a 'zip' like function where as my user scrolls each element moves in from the right/left until the element has a right (or left) value of 0.

I want my first elements to move first, then my second and so on...

Ive created a fiddle to show you all an example, has anybody advice on how i could do this? would it be best to check the `$('.row').top;` position?

http://jsfiddle.net/wBhzC/1/

Thanks

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
//if($('.right').css('right') == '0px'){
$('.right').css({
    'right' : +($(this).scrollTop()+(-200)/1)+"px",
});

$('.left').css({
    'right' : +($(this).scrollTop()+(-200)/1)+"px",
});
});
```

Comment: `$('.row').css("top");` right now its `auto`

Comment: Have a look at [jQuery Scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/); this plugin makes it a lot easier to implement such effects...